# Finding N most frequently occurring substrings of length K in a large set of strings

Tags: c++, string, hashmap, substring, unordered-map

As the title says I am trying to find N most frequent K-length substrings and their frequency in a large number of strings. Strings are read from a file line by line. (there are approximately 5 million lines). For example, if the input file is,

**TTTTTGCAG**

**GCAGGTTTT**

and K=4, N=2 then the output should be,

**TTTT - 3 occurrences**

**GCAG - 2 occurrences**

The sample file consists of DNA sequences. However, I want to conclude a generalized solution.

---

What I've done so far is :

1. Read all lines into a `std::vector<std::string>`
2. Initialize a hashmap `std::unoredered_map<std::string_view, unsigned int>`
3. For each line get all `line.length()-K+1` substrings.
4. For each substring, if it is already in our map increment it's
   frequency, otherwise, insert it.
5. Transfer all entries of our map to `std::multimap<unsigned int,
   std::string_view>` and get last N values and print them.

I have used `string_view` instead of `strings` to get substrings more efficiently and not to waste memory for each key.

---

This approach works but I am trying to find a more optimal solution. I think the problem is as input size gets bigger, the average time for insert/search in hashmap goes to `O(N)` instead of `O(1)`. Is that true and what can I do in order to improve my runtime/memory usage?

(I also tried Tries but, they are not memory efficient even if the alphabet size is 4 (A, C, G, T) and traversing them to find N most frequent ones is another difficulty)

Comment: There is no way you can load 5 billion lines into a vector.
EDIT - well, unless you have ~50Gb of heap lying around.

Comment: To improve memory usage, you can use container.reserve(). That would only mean one memory allocation would happen at the start of your processing, and no needless copies of data will happen during reallocation.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it should have been "million". And when I try to process one line at a time, I have to abandon string_view option. I applied both and it turns out reading all of them into a vector and processing is better.

Comment: @Alex Hodges I have tried to use reserver() method. It helped a bit. Still I am after better solutions.

Comment: using a `string_view` as a key in a map seems really fragile and error-prone... (Anyways, see edit to my answer for a working example of what I was talking about)

Comment: I'm aware of the issues with `string_view` but it gives better performance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

Instead of an `unordered_map`, use a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>`, that will be sorted on the string. When scanning all the substrings of each line you read, look them up in that with a binary search (`std::lower_bound()` is useful), inserting or updating as appropriate (If it's a small fixed alphabet like DNA, you might even generate all length-`K` substrings ahead of time and pre-populate the vector to avoid insertion overhead later).

When done, re-sort the vector based on the counts in descending order... `std::partial_sort()` would be really handy there, as you only need the first `N` elements:

```
std::partial_sort(words.begin(), words.begin() + N, words.end(),
                  [](const auto &a, const auto &b){ return a.second > b.second; });
```

---

Basically, something along the lines of:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>

constexpr std::size_t K = 4;
constexpr std::size_t N = 2;

int main() {
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> words;
  std::string line;

  while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    auto len = line.size();
    for (auto i = 0U; i < len - K + 1; i += 1) {
      auto word = std::string_view(line.c_str() + i, K);
      auto pos = std::lower_bound(words.begin(), words.end(), word,
                                  [](const auto &a, const auto &b){
                                    return a.first < b;
                                  });
      if (pos == words.end() || pos->first != word) {
        words.emplace(pos, std::string(word), 1);
      } else {
        pos->second += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  auto sort_to = std::min(words.size(), N);
  std::partial_sort(words.begin(), words.begin() + sort_to, words.end(),
                    [](const auto &a, const auto &b){
                      return a.second > b.second;
                    });
  for (auto i = 0U; i < sort_to; i += 1) {
    std::cout << words[i].first << " - " << words[i].second << " occurences\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, it seems this approach is much slower than the hashmap approach. For large k values (say 20), it is hard to keep all keys sorted, I think that's why it takes too much time.